# How to use altovaxml.exe with parameters in powershell

Tags: xslt, powershell, altova

I'm using a powershell script to run altovaxml.exe to transform a xml file to another:

```
.\AltovaXML -xslt2 test.xsl -in $element -out $tmpname -param name1=$value1 -param name2=$value2 -param name3='string1' and so on
```

The first problem I have is, I get an error by using variables as a value of a parameter:

```
parameter is not a valid xpath 2.0 expression: name1
```

(something like that, the error is in german)

Using only strings as values of the parameters, I don't get an error but I can't use them in the xsl file. There is no output.

But - and that's what I don't understand - it works using the command-line interface itself (of course without variables for -in, -out or -param)

Has anybody an idea how to run the altovaxml.exe correctly using powershell?

Comment: Could you try: `.\AltovaXML -xslt2 test.xsl -in $element -out $tmpname -param name1="$value1" -param name2="$value2" -param name3="string1"`. Works?

Comment: Add full path of AltovaXML.exe